# What is a 'Trace Crossing'?

Tags: electrochemistry, polymers, terminology

I'm reading about electrodeposition of conductive polymers in a chemistry textbook, and the author mentions 'trace-crossing' in the 'potentiodynamic response'. From the context I can figure out that 'potentiodynamic response' means cyclic voltammogram.  But what is the 'trace crossing'?

Answer (score 3):

'Trace crossing' is in the literal sense, where 'trace' is another word for 'line'. 'Trace crossing' basically means that the line in the voltammogram crosses itself.

Comment: It would be great if you edited your answer to include a short explanation of _when_ the voltammogram crosses itself and why it is important :)